# single page login system using ajax and pdo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is make a login system without page refreshing using ajax and pdo. Because Im planning to do is make a single page website where people can login and go to his profile using show and hide javascript only.

My problem is when  i press the login button nothing happens.

index.php

```
<?php include_once('myIncludes.php'); ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#login').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var emptyFieldsUser = $('#user').filter(function () { return this.value === '' });
       var emptyFieldsPass = $('#pass').filter(function () { return this.value === '' });
       if (emptyFieldsUser.length) && (emptyFieldsPass.length) {
           alert("try again");
       } else {
           var data = {};
           data.user_text = $('#user').val();
           data.pass_text = $('#pass').val();

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "user.php",
               data: data,
               cache: false,
               success: function (response) {
                   alert("login sccessfully!");
               }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">    
        Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" /><br />
        Password: <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" /><br />
        <button type="submit" name="login" id="login">Login</Button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

myIncludes.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('user.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $object = new User();
    $object->Login($user, $pass);
}
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
class User{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function Login($user, $pass){
        if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $user);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                echo "User verifies, Access granted";
            } else {
                echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Please enter Username and Password";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
class Connection{
    public function dbConnect(){
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', '');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your data hash seems to be wrong. if you have a input with the name "user" you also have to pass {"user" : $(...).val()}

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` won't be set as you're preventing the default submit action and assigning the `POST` values manually. You'll have to set `submit` in your `data` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your javascript:

```
if (emptyFieldsUser.length) && (emptyFieldsPass.length) {
                          ^ The if is closed here
```

And you probably want OR instead of AND, negating the conditions:

```
if (!emptyFieldsUser.length || !emptyFieldsPass.length) {
```

In your php you also have some problems:

- You are not sending your submit button so to check for a post you should check one of the two values you are sending or use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`;
- Your post variables will be `$_POST['user_text'];` and `$_POST['pass_text'];` as that is what you are setting your keys to in your ajax function.

Also note that when you reach your javascript success function, that does not mean that the login was successful. It only means the php script ran successfully. You should use the response you get back.

Comment: well, you should update your post then to provide the full answer.. cause after these changes nothing happens as well (you'll be able to debug the error better tho..)

Comment: the biggest one is the incorrect data hash - he is providing data values and his php script won't be doing anything with them

Comment: @gulty I'm not sure what the biggest problem is, even an unsuccesful login results in a success message. Anyway, edited to be more complete.